# Add Class to knp menu root Element with Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, knpmenubundle

what is the correct way to add a class to `knp_menu's` root element `<ul>` with twig?

i tried a lot of things:

1.

```
{{ knp_menu_render('main', {'class': 'foo'}) }}
```

2.

```
{{ knp_menu_render('main', {'attributes': {'class': 'foo'}}) }}
```

3.

```
{{ knp_menu_render('main', {'listAttributes': {'class': 'foo'}}) }}
```

4.

```
{{ knp_menu_render('main', {'attributes': {'listAttributes': {'class': 'foo'}}}) }}
```

none of them worked

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can add it in your menu builder like..

```
$menu = $this->factory->createItem('root', array(
    'childrenAttributes'    => array(
        'class'             => 'foo',
    ),
));
```

**Update**

I just got a notification about this and found another way although it requires you to use a custom template to achieve it.

In your custom template you need to override the `list` block like..

```
{% block list %}
    {% if item.hasChildren and options.depth is not sameas(0) and item.displayChildren %}
        {% import 'knp_menu.html.twig' as knp_menu %}
        <ul{{ knp_menu.attributes(listAttributes|merge({'class': [
                options.rootClass is defined ? options.rootClass : '',
                listAttributes.class is defined ? listAttributes.class : ''
            ]|join(' ')
        })) }}>
            {% set options = options|merge({'rootClass': '' }) %}
            {{ block('children') }}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

In this rather than use `knp_menu.attributes(listAttributes)` you pass in a array with your on-the-fly generated `listAttributes.class` value. This attribute is generate by joining `option.rootClass` (if it exists) with `listAttributes.class` (if it exists) as the `listAttributes.class` value.

The `option.rootClass` value is reset to `''` after use using `{% set options = options|merge({'rootClass': '' }) %}` so that it is not added to every sub-menu.

This will allow you to render your menu using..

```
{{ knp_menu_render('main', {'rootClass': 'foo' }) }}
```

Comment: is this the only way i can do it? not as a param?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, sorry.

Comment: i'll upvote your answer, but not accept it, because it is not the solution i want...

Comment: would you please kindly shed some more light on how and where to create this template file and how to use it? I can not get it to work. tnx

Comment: This was quite a while ago so I can't be sure but I think you would need to set you template location in the `knp_menu` config under `twig.template`. See http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/index.html#step-3-optional-configure-the-bundle

Answer (score 3):

Have not found a clean solution to pass params in view also. My solution in the `builder` class:

`$menu->setChildrenAttribute('id', 'boo')
    ->setChildrenAttribute('class', 'foo');`

Comment: You can also use the `$menu->setChildrenAttributes(['id' => 'myId', 'class' => 'myClass']);` method to set multiple attributes.

Comment: question is set class in template not in builder

Answer (score 1):

Try to

```
{% set menu = knp_menu_get('AppBundle:Builder:categoriesMenu', [], {'childrenAttributes': {'class': 'menu'}}) %}
{{ knp_menu_render(menu) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{% set menu = knp_menu_get('AppBundle:Builder:mainMenu', []) %}
{% do menu.setChildrenAttribute('class', 'child-class') %}
{% knp_menu_render(menu, {'currentClass': 'active'}) %}
```

found here https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu/issues/166